# Joining 2 or more tables in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, join, foreign-keys

I want to join 2 or more table in my Hotel management project, so what all are the steps to join tables?
Is it necessary to give foreign key in each table we need to join or works without foreign key?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... could you describe the situation more thoroughly ? What two tables are you trying to merge, and what is the expected result?

Comment: I have created following tables-
1)alloted
2)guest
3)menu
4)ordersfood 5)room 6)Check-out

Comment: What tables are you trying to join and in what way exactly?

Comment: All are to be linked, because when any guest will be checking-out, a bill will be generated from room rates, ordered food etc.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:

1. Write a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) query. You're done!

You can `JOIN` using columns that are neither a primary key nor foreign key. E.g.,

```
select *
from (select 'x' as a) t1
inner join (select 'x' as a) t2 on t1.a = t2.a
```

A query has a `JOIN` clause and an `ON` clause. The `JOIN` clause says [what type of `JOIN`](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) it is and which tables are being `JOIN`ed. The `ON` clause specifies which columns to `JOIN` on.

Comment: of course all guests won't order food, so those tables will need to be joined with a LEFT join.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to use foreign keys specifically, although you will probably use an equivalent. (note, the default engine MyISAM, does not support foreign keys, if you want to use them, use InnoDB or $otherEngine).

For joins I would suggest reading [the documentation on joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simple join, without redundant ID output:

SELECT * FROM foo JOIN bar USING (id);

Assuming the id column is defined in both tables as primary, hence creating the relationship between tables you want to join.

However, there are different type of joins (natural, straight, left, right), based on what criteria and requirements you have. Check out the MySQL API manual, it will provide you with sufficient information.

Answer (score -1):

I think for your situation (as explained in the top post) , It would make more sense to create a PHP file to fetch the guest's data for each one of the tables separately , as for me at least it seems JOINing 6 tables together would be too cumbersome and not very effective in the practical way.